# Predicting the future with pandas and statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

What i need to do  is plot future temperature with these "requirments" : " assume that temperature is roughly a linear function of CO2 emission,
estimating the coefficients of the linear function from recent data points (using
the past 2 is fine, as is using the past 10 or so if you want to be more thorough).
Further, assume that the rate of increase of CO2 emissions is going to be the
same as it is today (i.e. if there were X tons more CO2 emissions in 2016 than
in 2015, there will be X tons more CO2 emissions in 2017 than in 2016)".

I have 2 data sets, one with temperature for each month per year, and one with Carbon level per year.

(posted the merged and shortened down one as its not that big, but if its more helpful to see them unmodified then i can post that as well, you can see how its done below where i post my code)

```
Year    Carbon    June

2000    6727  20.386
2001    6886  20.445
2002    6946  20.662
2003    7367  20.343
2004    7735  20.242
2005    8025  20.720
2006    8307  20.994
2007    8488  20.661
2008    8738  20.657
2009    8641  20.548
2010    9137  21.027
2011    9508  20.915
2012    9671  21.172
```

What i have done so far is to merge the two datasets together and then try to predict temperature for one month for future years, i have limited it down to 2000-2012 just to make it simplerer and make sure that both tables have the same length as one table is longer than the other. I am pretty new to python and coding overall and i have no idea how to do this, below you can see what i have tried to far:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("co2.csv", sep=',')
data2 = pd.read_csv("temperature.csv", sep=',')

data1 = data1.set_index('Year')
data2 = data2.set_index('Year')

data3 = data1.loc["2000":"2012"]

data4 = data2.loc["2000":"2012"]

data4 = data4.loc[:, "June":"June"]

data5 = pd.merge(data3,data4, how= 'left', left_index =True , right_index=True)

x = data5["Carbon"]

y = data5["June"]

model = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()

prediction = model.predict(x)

prediction.plot()


plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you heard from `R` and `Rstudio`? A great program to handle data!

Comment: I have not, but i will check it out :D

Comment: Is this homework? If so, see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @itzy Hey, its practise for exam, we got some tasks we should try do before exam to get better understanding. not sure if that would count as homework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`OLS.predict`](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict) do not take `x` as arguments but the model parameters (and eventually exogenous data). Besides, you have to add a constant to X, otherwise it force the linear regression to pass through the origin. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from StringIO import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
Year Carbon June
2000 6727 20.386
2001 6886 20.445
2002 6946 20.662
2003 7367 20.343
2004 7735 20.242
2005 8025 20.720
2006 8307 20.994
2007 8488 20.661
2008 8738 20.657
2009 8641 20.548
2010 9137 21.027
2011 9508 20.915
2012 9671 21.172
""")

# Model training
df = pd.read_table(data, index_col=0, sep='\s+')
Y_train = df['June']
X_train = df['Carbon']
X_train = sm.add_constant(X_train) # add this to your code
model = sm.OLS(Y_train, X_train)
results = model.fit()

# Prediction of future values
future_carbon = range(9700, 10000, 50)
X_pred = pd.DataFrame(data=future_carbon, columns=['Carbon'])
X_pred = sm.add_constant(X_pred)
prediction = model.predict(results.params, X_pred)

# Plot
plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_train['Carbon'], model.predict(results.params), '-r', label='Linear model')
plt.plot(X_pred['Carbon'], prediction, '--r', label='Linear prediction')
plt.scatter(df['Carbon'], df['June'], label='data')
plt.xlabel('Carbon')
plt.ylabel('June temperature')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty sure this is just what i needed. just need to modify it a little :D just one question how do i make it go past known data? cuz in your picture it stops at last known data( as in predict future data)

Comment: @cryseth Exogenous data in the `predict` method may refer to any data including future data.

Comment: Thank you, but i stil dont really get it. would it be possible for you to make a quick example? thank you very much for the help so far, got me a lot futher.

Comment: @cryseth I just made an edit. I add the suffix `_train` and `_pred` to make the distinction between the training and the prediction set. By the way, you may find the API of [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression) more convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a ton.